# Modify a Nested Path Element in JSON Array - MySQL

Tags: mysql, json

Can anyone help me solve the issue?

**How do I modify the isActive item under one of the roles here**

The following is a JSON object in my mysql table.

```
    {
      "departments": [{}],
      "roles": [
        "{'position': 'IT Head', 'report': 'Director', 'project': 'Bank1', 'isActive': {'active': 'no', 'transferredTo': 'Bank2'}}",
        "{'position': 'Manager', 'report': 'Director', 'project': 'Bank2', 'isActive': {'active': 'yes', 'transferredTo': ''}}"
      ],
      "paybands": [{}]
    }
```

I have tried the following.

```
set @newdict="{'active': 'no', 'transferredTo': 'Bank3'}"

update table set column = JSON_REPLACE(column, '$.roles.[*].isActive', @newDict )  where column->'$.roles[*].position' = 'Manager' ;
```

I read that JSON_REPLACE won't take wildcard[*] to loop through items in a JSON array. Is there any way to modify the required element? Thanks.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using? Do you have only one position per role (roles.position="Manager" only one)?

Comment: Hi! MySQL 8. Yeah, only one active position. The 'active' key under 'isActive' (which is a dictionary) will define the state of the position.

Comment: Try [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4e8fbffbf4e1d26d11414139a2faef69).